# Is there a Visual c++ compiler online and how convert between c++ and vs simple code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assert

Is there any particular problem in converting these kind of code into VS2010(I have to know before I can check it)

Is there any online VS2010 compiler?

**What does `assert(false);` does?**

EXAMPLE

```
    int applyOperator(Operator op,int x,int y)
{
  switch (op) {
    case operator_plus:  return x+y; // jesli operator_plus zwroc x + y itd.
    case operator_minus: return x-y;
    case operator_mul: return x*y;
    case operator_div: return x/y;
    case operator_none:
      break;
  }
  assert(false);
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Student {
public:
    string Name, ID, Gender, BirthDate, Major;
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Student& s); //DEKLARACJA przeciazenia operatora >> tak bay wczytywal dane linia po linii
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&,Student const&);  //DEKLARACJA przeciazenia operatora << tak aby wypisywal obiekty typu Student
};


   istream& operator >> (istream& in, Student& s){
    cout << "Name\n";
    getline (cin,s.Name); //wczytanie linii na imię
    cout <<"ID\n";
    getline (cin,s.ID);   //wczytanie linii na ID
    cout <<"Gender\n";    
    getline (cin,s.Gender);
    cout <<"BirthDate\n";
    getline (cin,s.BirthDate);
    cout <<"Major\n";
    getline (cin,s.Major);
    return in;
    };
ostream& operator<< (ostream &wyjscie, Student const& ex)
{
   wyjscie<<""<<"Name:\t"<<ex.Name<<"\n"<<
    ""<<"Student ID:\t"<<ex.ID<<"\n"<<
    ""<<"Gender:\t"<<ex.Gender<<"\n"<<
    "BirthDate:\t"<<ex.BirthDate<<"\n"<<
    "Major:\t"<<ex.Major<<endl;
    return wyjscie;
}



int main(){
        Student s;
        cin>>s;
        cout<<s;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: www.ideone.com www.codepad.org

Comment: AFAIK yes,and ................its on my localhost ;)

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: Both use gcc, not Visual C++.

Comment: Ok, what that assert(false)does. I've read some description but as every description of C++ it is weird.

Comment: @RobertKilar it alerts you when that code is reached.

Comment: @RobertKilar it's basically a raised alarm.

Comment: 3 different questions in 1, 1st does not seem like a proper one to ask here, 3rd is something a simple Google search would answer.

Comment: With respect to online compiler this is a good thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does assert(false); does?

It opens an assert window. It's a mechanism to let the programmer know when a control path that wasn't supposed to be reached, is, or a condition that wasn't supposed to fail, does.

Basically like:

```
int divide10ByX(int x)
{
   if ( x == 0 )
   {
      assert(!"x can't be 0");
      return 0;
   }
   return 10/x;
}
```

When `x` is `0`, the program would normally crash. By checking beforehand, you prevent the crash, but can hide some wrong functionality because `x` isn't supposed to be 0. So you put an assert there to inform you whenever `x` is 0.

Alternitively, it could be `assert(x)`, which only triggers if `x==0`.

Comment: what would be the diff to assert(true);

Comment: @RobertKilar the assert only triggers if the condition inside is false.

Answer (score 0):

Since Visual Studio is a commercial product, I'd guess that you're unlikely to come across a free on-line VC++ compiler unless Microsoft provide such a facility.

The `assert` macro is used to validate a true boolean condition. This is usually done to validate expected conditions as part of [Design by Contract](http://www.eiffel.com/developers/design_by_contract.html) or something similar when developing code and is compiled out of production code i.e. when debugging is disabled.

Encountering a false condition will cause a message to be output to stderr and `abort()` to be called. Therefore `assert(false)` is simply forcing the code (in debug) to abort at a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention behind "online compiler" is a "free" compiler before you can purchase the fully licensed one, you can use [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express). It is fully functional for most of the basic needs.

Comment: It crashed in very very epic way on my PC.